# How to mock a return value?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have a class:

```
 public class BankingTransfer : IBankingTransfer
 {
    public decimal GetTrustAccountBalance(string Id, string Pin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Now I want to do a xunit test on it. But not sure how to test a dummy return value?

My code:

```
 public class GetTrustAccountBalanceUnitTest
 {
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("1234")]
    [InlineData("1234")]
    public void GetTrustAccountBalance_Should_Return_A_Value(string expectedId,string expectedPin)
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var bankingTransferMock =new Mock<IBankingTransfer>();
        // ACT
        bankingTransferMock.Setup(x=>x.GetTrustAccountBalance(expectedId,expectedPin)).Returns()
        // ASSURE
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Returns(42m)`? What is your question, what is the output of this code, what have you tried? It also makes no sense to mock the class under test. You'll be testing Moq, not your class.

Comment: I have no actual implementation of the class. At the very beginning, how to test it? I don't care the return value.

Comment: Then why are you asking for a return value in your question? What do you want to test exactly? May I suggest reading a book about unit testing basics? You're asking the wrong questions, so to say, which requires answerers to cover unit testing basics, which makes the question too broad.

Comment: Because the method returns a value. The method is not a void method. If it were void, I would use `bankingTransferMock .Verify()`.

Comment: Yes, but again, you're mocking the class under test. That is wrong to begin with, so the rest of the question doesn't make that much sense I'm afraid.

Comment: Fundamentally, you really need to think about what piece of code you're trying to test.

Comment: Maybe my idea is wrong, I shouldn't put the expected strings. I want to mock the `Id` and `Pin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a value inside the returns value like this:

```
bankingTransferMock.Setup(x=>x.GetTrustAccountBalance(expectedId,expectedPin)).Returns(1);
```

However, I think that you have misunderstood how to test the class that you have displayed. You shouldn't mock the class that you are trying to test. Going by the test name you probably want something more along these lines where you are just calling the method and seeing what is returned.

```
var bankingTransfer = new BankingTransfer();
Assert.True(bankingTransfer.GetTrustAccountBalance("", "") > 0);
```

Comment: I  mean I really don't want to use `1234` as `Id` and `Pin`. I want to mock them.

Comment: I don't think that you need to mock a string object since it is such a simple type just pass in actual strings.